# Creating a patch config file for Rainbow.SFS.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength

Tags: unicorn

How can I add a patch file for Rainbow.Config? Is there a naming convention that I need to follow?

I need to modify below setting, but don't want to change the main Rainbow.Config file.

```
<setting name="Rainbow.SFS.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength" value="150" />
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Be sure to do a FULL RESERIALIZE of all Unicorn configurations when you change this setting.

Comment: Hope it can help. https://mskutta.github.io/2017/08/09/sitecore-patchinstead-in-config/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a patch file; `z.Rainbow.config`.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
      <settings>
        <setting name="Rainbow.SFS.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength" set:value="150" />
      </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Write your patch file as below:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <settings>
           <setting name="Rainbow.SFS.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength" set:value="150" />
       </settings>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

When you will publish your patch file it will update the value. You can check in showconfig.aspx. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this won't work.

Answer (score -2):

Sitecore Patch functionality can resolve your problem. Patch file will replace your setting. Below are the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Rainbow.SFS.SerializationFolderPathMaxLength">
        <patch:attribute name="value">150</patch:attribute>
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can find more detail here
[Sitecore Patch](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configuration-patch-file-examples.html)

Comment: I would recommend adding the code sample directly to your answer so that others can copy and paste (have a look at Mark's answer for an example).